How to show all columns on a table with lots of columns?
I've got an Ibis table (duckdb backend) t and I'm in interactive mode (ibis.options.interactive=True). When I try to see the first couple of rows (t.head()) ibis only shows the first three columns:

As I'd like to see all columns I wonder whether there is an option to see all the columns of my table, something like pandas pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)? Unfortunately I couldn't find anything like that in ibis.options.

Docs aren't great, but you can use ibis.options.repr.interactive.max_columns to adjust the maximum number of columns displayed:
In [8]: from ibis.interactive import *

In [9]: t = ibis.memtable({"a": [1, 2], "b": [3, 4], "c": [5, 6], "d": [7, 8]})

In [10]: ibis.options.repr.interactive.max_columns = 10

In [11]: t
Out[11]:
┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┓
┃ a     ┃ b     ┃ c     ┃ d     ┃
┡━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━┩
│ int64 │ int64 │ int64 │ int64 │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│     1 │     3 │     5 │     7 │
│     2 │     4 │     6 │     8 │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘

In [12]: ibis.options.repr.interactive.max_columns = 2

In [13]: t
Out[13]:
┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━┓
┃ a     ┃ b     ┃ … ┃
┡━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━╇━━━┩
│ int64 │ int64 │ … │
├───────┼───────┼───┤
│     1 │     3 │ … │
│     2 │     4 │ … │
└───────┴───────┴───┘

